# неправильная работа функции в python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть задача - написать функцию, которая считает количество определенных букв в слове. Похоже, моя программа выполняет функцию только один раз, т.к. если ввести слово `абракадабра` и для поиска выбрать букву `а` она находит только 1 букву. Да, еще я дал одно и то же название как для функции, так и для переменной. Плохо ли это, могут ли из за этого  возникнуть проблемы в работе?

```
def count():
    count = 0
    for i in name:
        if i == letter:
            count =+ 1
print("there are", count, letter + "'s", "in", name)
name = str(input("enter the word: "))
letter = str(input("enter the letter: "))
count()
input()
```

Comment: У вас синтаксическая ошибка в коде: вместо `count =+ 1`, должно быть `count += 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно просто сделать вот так:

```
word='testtesttest'
t_count = word.count('t')
```

А по поводу имён, в вашем случае count локальная переменная и она определена только в теле функции. Если бы она была глобальной, то были бы прооблемы.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае у вас `count` - локальная переменная, извне функции она недоступна. Проблему можно решить возвращая значение из функции:

```
def count(name, letter):
    cnt = 0
    for i in name:
        if i == letter:
            cnt += 1
    return cnt

nam = str(input("enter the word: "))
let = str(input("enter the letter: "))
c = count(let, nam)
print("there are", c, let + "'s", "in", nam)
input()
```

Другие проблемы в вашем коде:

- `=+` (что эквивалентно двум операторам `= +`) вместо `+=`
- попытка вывода результата до вызова функции (вызов `print` до вызова функции `count`).